# Remove \u from string?

Tags: python, regex, python-unicode, unicode-escapes

I have a few words in a list that are of the type `'\uword'`. I want to replace the `'\u'` with an empty string. I looked around on SO but nothing has worked for me so far. I tried converting to a raw string using `"%r"%word` but that didn't work. I also tried using `word.encode('unicode-escape')` but haven't gotten anywhere. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Adding code

```
word = '\u2019'
word.encode('unicode-escape')
print(word) # error

word = '\u2019'
word = "%r"%word
print(word) # error
```

Comment: Please include some code, showing what you have already tried.

Comment: `'\uword'.replace(r'\u', '')` -> `'word'`

Comment: replace `\\u` with ''

Comment: @Petar added code

Comment: @ClockSlave when you say you get an error, what do you mean? Running the given code does not produce errors.

Comment: @Petar I am getting `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2019' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>` for both the cases. I'm using python 3

Comment: @Petar are you entering `word` on the console or `print(word)`? entering `word` doesn't give an error but printing does

Comment: @martineau running that gives `SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \uXXXX escape`

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: @jwodder using python 3

Comment: @ClockSlave I am having to test it here: https://repl.it/languages/python3 at the moment; I am not getting any errors.

Comment: @Petar using the `.encode` method, the `print(word)` line outputs `’` in the console you linked. I am still getting the error when I run the code on my command prompt. I guess I know what I was doing wrong. I was assuming '.encode' is an inplace method like `.sort()` method of lists. I thought that it would change the string. I read the docs, it says `.encode()` 
>>returns a bytes representation of the Unicode string, encoded in the requested encoding

Comment: @ClockSlave yes, you are 100% correct. Good spot. You should submit it as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was making an error in assuming that the `.encode` method of strings modifies the string inplace similar to the `.sort()` method of a list. But according to the documentation

> The opposite method of bytes.decode() is str.encode(), which returns a bytes representation of the Unicode string, encoded in the requested encoding.

```
def remove_u(word):
    word_u = (word.encode('unicode-escape')).decode("utf-8", "strict")
    if r'\u' in word_u: 
        # print(True)
        return word_u.split('\\u')[1]
    return word

vocabulary_ = [remove_u(each_word) for each_word in vocabulary_]
```

Answer (score 2):

Given that you are dealing with strings only.
We can simply convert it to string using the **string function**.

```
>>> string = u"your string"
>>> string
u'your string'
>>> str(string)
'your string'
```

Guess this will do!

Answer (score 1):

If I have correctly understood, you don't have to use regular expressions. Just try:

```
>>> # string = '\u2019'
>>> char = string.decode('unicode-escape')
>>> print format(ord(char), 'x')
2019
```

Answer (score -2):

Because you are facing problems with encodings and unicode it would be helpful to know the version of python you are using.
I don't know if I get you right but this should do the trick:

```
string = r'\uword'
string.replace(r'\u','')
```

Comment: I don't have a raw string. I have a string literal of the form `'\u2019'`. The above method doesn't work when `string = '\u2019'`